# Anyone knows why I have this error: undefined is not an object(evaluating 'messages.filter')

Tags: react-native

Why am I getting the following error

```
undefined is not an object(evaluating 'messages.filter')
```

with the following code?

```js
    import React,{useState} from 'react';
    import { FlatList, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'
    import ListItem from './../components/ListItem';
    import ListItemSeparator from './../components/ListItemSeparator';
    import ListItemDeleteAction from './../components/ListItemDeleteAction';
    
    const initialMessages =[
        {id:1 ,userName:"Anna",description:"An awesome girl"},
        {id:2 ,userName:"Lucy",description:"A best people"},
        {id:3 ,userName:"Jack",description:"Very good guy"}
    ]
    
    
    function MessagesScreen(props) {
        const[messages,setMessages] = useState(initialMessages);
       
    
        const handleDelete = message =>{
           const newMessages = messages.filter(m => m.id !== message.id);
           setMessages(newMessages);
        }
        return (
            <View>
               <FlatList
               data ={initialMessages}
               keyExtractor = {message => message.id.toString()}
               renderItem ={({item})=>(
                   <ListItem
                   image = {require('../assets/me.jpg')}
                   title = {item.userName}
                   subTitle ={item.description}
                   onPress ={()=>console.log(item)}
                   renderRightActions ={()=>(
                       <ListItemDeleteAction onPress={()=>handleDelete(item)}/>
                   )}
                   />
               )}
               ItemSeparatorComponent ={ListItemSeparator}
               /> 
            </View>
        );
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        
    })
    
    export default MessagesScreen;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give the wrong element in handleDelete.

The argument 'item' in your renderItem is an element of your 'initialMessages' not your array.

> undefined is not an object(evaluating 'messages.filter')

This error means that you are trying to call filter() on a json. This function does not exist, so it is undefined.

Try this code.

```
<ListItemDeleteAction onPress={()=>handleDelete(messages)}/>
```